# git does not mark untracked files

Tags: tortoisegit

I use tortoisegit for version control. It does show the modified files but untracked files are not marked. This did not happen before Windows 11 but keeps happening all of my computers (laptop and PCs). Sorry if this is an older question but I could not find a similar problem. Anyone has a solution for that?

I add files to a folder which is tracked by git. But no icons appear on the new file. On modified files, icons appear as normal. When I try to commit they do appear but no icons.

Comment: https://tortoisegit.org/support/faq/#ovlnotshowing